# correct formatting in jquery, htmls pecial characters

Tags: jquery

I have a little jQuery that updates price information based on database.
Somehow, when I use a currency symbol which is encoded (for example the Indian Rupees symbol ₨) it displays the symbol as a string, not as a html special character.

How can I fix this?

The code that is relevant:

```
$('#price').text("<?php echo $prefix; ?>" + val + "<?php echo $suffix; ?>");
```

On the website source with the above example (Indian Rupees) it looks like this:

```
$('#price').text("" + "1000.00" + "&#8360;");
```

And the result displayed on the website is:

```
0.00&#8360;
```

Comment: use .html() rather than .text(), but it likely still won't fix the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, using .html() will solve your issue.

Here is a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2Sh3/

```
$('#price').html("" + "1000.00" + "&#8360;");
```

The result printed is:

```
1000.00₨
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I posted the answer also simultaneously with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin B, this actually handles the problem:

```
$('#price').html("<?php echo $prefix; ?>" + val + "<?php echo $suffix; ?>");
```